# How to remove one radio button's post value to render new radio selection result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am working on a module with 3 radio buttons. Clicking one radio button lists data related to it and so on. I have applied ajax call on radio buttons click and return an array in the response. My problem here is for each radio button click the data keeps on adding into the list. For e.g. if I click on 'All users' radio it displays the data related to "All" but again if I click on "Unapproved Users" radio, the list adds up to the 'All users '  listing at the bottom. So how can I reset the $_POST variable each time the data is rendered so that new list appears for new radio selection, 
I would really appreciate the help or advice for this.

Code goes as,

```
 <script>
        $('#selection').change
        (

            function() 
            {
              var selected_value = $("input[name='users']:checked").val();
              //till here the code works fine.
$.ajax
                ( 
                    {
                        url: "approval_ajax.php",
                        dataType : "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        cache: false,
                        data: { selected_value : selected_value },

                        success: function(response)
                        {
                             console.log(response);
                                var len = response.length;
                           for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                                 var id = response[i].id;
                                 var email = response[i].email;
                                 var employee_id = response[i].employee_id;
                                 var first_name = response[i].first_name;
                                 var middle_name = response[i].middle_name;
                                 var last_name = response[i].last_name;
                                 var mobile = response[i].mobile;
                                 var created_on = response[i].created_on;
                                 var disabled = response[i].disabled;

                    var tr_str = "<tr>" +
                        "<td>" + (i+1) + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + email + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + employee_id + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + first_name + "&nbsp;" + middle_name + "&nbsp;" + last_name + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + mobile + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + created_on + "</td>" +
                        "<td><input type='checkbox' name='check[]'"  + disabled +  "value= '"  + id +  "' class='checkbox' id='select_all' ></td>" +
                          "<input type='hidden' value='"  + id +  "' name='user_id' id='user_id' >" +
                        "</tr>";

                    $("#example").append(tr_str);
                }
                           alert("AJAX was a success");
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    </script>
```

And now my **approval_ajax.php**

```
  <?php


session_start();

require("../includes/config.php"); 
require("../classes/Database.class.php"); 
$db = new Database(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);  

$return_arr = array();
$status=''; 

   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
   {
       $value = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "selected_value");


       if (isset($value))
       {
         $users=$value;

}else{
    $users='';
}

switch ($users)

{

case "all":
  $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE type =3";       

break;

case "approved":
  $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE type =3 AND status =1";   
break;

case "unapproved":
  $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE type =3 AND status =0";   

break;

}

$sq = $db->query($sqlQuery);


if ($db->affected_rows > 0) {

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sq)) {
    $disabled = '';
    if ($status == '1') {

        $disabled = "disabled = 'disabled' checked='checked' ";
    }

    $id = $row['id'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    $employee_id = $row['employee_id'];
    $first_name = $row['first_name'];
    $middle_name = $row['middle_name'];
    $last_name = $row['last_name'];
    $mobile = $row['mobile'];
    $created_on1 = $row['created_on'];
    $created_on = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($created_on1));

    $return_arr[] = array("id" => $id,
    "email" => $email,
    "employee_id" => $employee_id,
    "first_name" => $first_name,
    "middle_name" => $middle_name,
    "last_name" => $last_name,
    "mobile" => $mobile,
    "created_on" => $created_on,
    "disabled" => $disabled
    );
}
}
header('Content-Type: application/json', true, 200);
echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the time but I did not get you. Can you be please specific.

Answer (score 1):

The $_POST variable is reset on every new request.

The issue here is that you're using jquery's [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function. This function just adds up content to the end of your element.

EDITED:
In order to clear your list before adding new data, use the [empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) function.

Comment: Thanks for the time but as directed by you to use html(), now the list sbows only the last record not all the record.

Comment: I see. I just realized you're building your table on the client-side. My bad. Try this: Go back to using the append function, but before your "for" loop, add this: $("#example").empty();

Comment: Thanks again. But it does not solves my issue. Using this removes my table headers. `#example` is id of the table and  it has classes, `<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered dataTableReport dt-responsive nowrap"   cellspacing="0" width="100%"> `

Comment: Okay, here's what you can do: Use the tbody tag to separate your content from your headers. That way, you can use the empty() and append() functions to your tbody, instead of the table itself. Can you try that?

Comment: I did not get your point I am sorry. Can you please just write down in here with respect to the code.

Comment: Your table needs to look something like this: <table class="your classes"><thead><tr><td>Field 1</td><td>Field 2</td>...</tr><tbody id="table-content"> <<Your content here >> </tbody></table> Then, you can use $("#table-content").empty() to clear the content of your table. Also, append your data (your "tr_str" var) to the #table-content element.

Comment: Tanks for this. Its sorted but now I want to state that the classes that I  have applied on the table does not applies on the listing. I mean to say in my clesses applied on table, its defined that to show 10 entries on basis of pagination but now it does not applies on the list coming and the whole list is being displayed. Can we sort that too?